# Stop eslint from choking on typescript's Non-null assertion operator?

Tags: typescript, eslint

The Unexpected token being referenced is `!`, the Non-null assertion operator. How could I still use the Non-null assertion operator and rid myself of this error?

```
 46:43  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token 

  16 | export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
> 18 |   @Prop({ default: 'Default Title' }) title!: string
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      legacyDecorators: true
    }
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotemark": 0,
    "whitespace": [0, "check-branch", "check-operator", "check-typecast", "check-preblock", "check-postbrace", "check-type"],
    "interface-name": 0,
    "ordered-imports": 0,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": 0,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": 0,
    "semicolon": 0,
    "vue/html-self-closing": ["error", {
      "html": {
        "void": "any",
        "normal": "any",
        "component": "always"
      },
      "svg": "never",
      "math": "never"
    }],
    "trailing-comma": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-string-literal": 0,
    "no-var-requires": 0, 
    "ban-types": 0,
  }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is correct - it might very well dislike `@`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did "prove it" by removing. editing question...

Comment: @VLAZ no, it likes @ just fine

Comment: Can you share your eslint configuration?

Comment: @TimPerry I've edited the question to include the config

Comment: Are you using non-standard Typescript features that require you to use `babel-eslint` parser?

Comment: @Retsam dunno, is Non-null assertion operator non-standard?

Comment: No, I meant features that babel can provide that aren't supported by the TS language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible this is simply a bug or a misconfiguration with `babel-eslint`, but if you're using Typescript with `eslint`, you'd likely be better off using the [`@typescript-eslint/parser`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/parser) - that's a parser designed to handle TS code.

With that parser you can also use the [`@typescript-eslint/plugin`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin) which has some eslint rules specific to linting Typescript code, and also some updated versions of base lint rules, to handle Typescript code better.

You can see the [README](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) for the `@typescript-eslint` monorepo; for some more information on using ESLint with Typescript.